# Issues overwriting a cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

Client has a site at a.url.com. Client creates a cookie with host as ".url.com" and path as "/". Client redirects to us at b.url.com. Client has a coding issue that requires us to delete the cookie (long story).

The following code is not adjusting the expiration at all in our test or production environments but is working fine locally.

```
if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
{
  HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
  myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
  Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We've done some more research. The cookie is actually created from www1, www2 or www3.url.com although this isn't important. We have tested that when we manually create the cookie and set the host value to the exact same value as our domain (like b.url.com), the code is updating the cookie. It does not work when the host value is set to the more general ".url.com". Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've figured it out. We needed to add one line of code to manually set the domain. Makes total sense now.

```
if (Request.Cookies["cookie"] != null)
{
  HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("cookie");
  myCookie.Domain = ".url.com";
  myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
  Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: This exactly i was going to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

is this a third party cookie? If so, the default security settings in IE will prevent cookie writing in the "internet" zone but it is allowed in your local zone.

Comment: No. They both share the same domain but just have different host a records like dog.animal.com and cat.animal.com.

Comment: The cookie is set by a page that is a few directories down. Cookie is set by http://a.url.com/a/b/page. After the redirect (different IP and different server), our code is happening at http://b.url.com/c/page. I don't think that's important because of the cookie path set to "/" but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack. I am just posting this in case you find out that you cannot do what you want due to some security issue preventing you handling the issue on the second site.

You could send a request to the first site to clear the cookie via redirect and have that site bounce the user back again. Like I said, this is very hackish (or I suppose marketing would call it inter-site cooperative security feature).

Hopefully, there's a better approach, but at least you have an alternative if no other ones are forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get it working in C# you might want to consider seeing if you can manipulate the cookies in javascript.

Gary